# Do there exist T helper memory cells?

Tags: immunology

I'm translating a Russian text touching upon the IL-17 interleukin family, and it has a kind of typo in it. I'm not sure:

> As mentioned above, IL-17 was found to be expressed at the highest levels by CD3+ Th17 cells. However, subsequent studies showed that it may be produced as well by stimulated CD8+ memory T cells, γδ T cells, **Th memory cells** (?) and NKT cells.

The Russian text says "Th memory", there is no "cells" there. It might be a typo.

I've read a little about T cells and became curious. Are there T helper memory cells, or does being a [T helper cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_helper_cell) exclude the possibility of being a [memory cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_T_cell) as well?

P.S. The original Russian sentence is

> Как уже было сказано выше, наибольшей экспрессией ИЛ-17 характеризуются CD4+ Th17 лимфоциты, однако последующие исследования установили, что стимулированные CD8+ Т-лимфоциты памяти, γδ Т-клетки, **Th памяти** и популяция NKT также способны к его продукции.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18825747

Comment: Also relevant, and open-access: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/eji.201343751/full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, T cells -- including T helper cells and cytotoxic T cells -- form memory cells.

- [CD4 memory T cells: what are they and what can they do?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2679806/)
- [Origins of CD4+ effector and central memory T cells](http://www.nature.com/ni/journal/v12/n6/full/ni.2038.html)
- [Immunological memory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27158/)
- [Control of innate immunity by memory CD4 T cells](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3771518/)